# GridView and Dynamically adding Items

Tags: c#, gridview, xamarin.android

I have searched a lot for this but really haven't found anything useful yet. So I am asking it here.

I am doing this in Xamarin Android and I have an `ItemsGrid` class which extends to `BaseAdapter`. Everything is working fine since I am able to populate the items and show the information I need to show but there is one thing that's not quite right and it is described as follows:

In my `GridView` I load more items dynamically as I click on a button but the first set of items is added when the activity is created. Everything works fine up to the point where I add more items. Because every time I add more items I set the `Adapter` to the `ItemsGrid` new instance (I use new instance every time). That way the items are loaded but the scroll viewer goes up to `zero` every time. So I added an auto scroll function to automatically scroll into view the first item of the newly created set of items.

The above is my approach currently but I am looking for something more nice and UI friendly as the new Items should be added after the already available items in the view as it happens with "UWP Apps in XAML".

Here is my code for "ItemsGrid.cs":

```
public class ItemsGrid : BaseAdapter
{

    private Context mContext;
    private int iCount = 0;
    private int mCount = 0;
    private string type = "";

    private int[] mThumbIds = new int[24];

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            mThumbIds = getIds();
            return mThumbIds.Count();
        }
    }

    public ItemsGrid(Context c, int initialCount, int maxCount, string itemType)
    {
        mContext = c;
        iCount = initialCount;
        mCount = maxCount;
        type = itemType;

    }

    private int[] getIds()
    {
        string[] ids = new string[10000];

        for (int b = iCount; b < mCount; b++)
        {
            ids[b] = b + "";
        }
        int[] x = new int[mCount];
        for (int a = 0; a < mCount; a++)
        {
            if (ids[a] != null)
            {
                x[a] = Convert.ToInt32(ids[a]);
            }
        }
        return x;
    }


    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
        TextView text = new TextView(mContext);
        TextView text2 = new TextView(mContext);
        TextView text3 = new TextView(mContext);
        if (type == "Movies")
        {
            Picasso.With(mContext).Load(MoviesActivity.MoviesImageLinks[position]).Into(image);
            text.Text = MoviesActivity.MoviesTitles[position];
            text2.Text = "Movie";
        }
        else if (type == "TV Shows")
        {
            Picasso.With(mContext).Load(TVShowsActivity.TVShowsImageLinks[position]).Into(image);
            text.Text = TVShowsActivity.TVShowsTitles[position];
            text2.Text = "TV Show";
        }
        else if (type == "Search")
        {
            Picasso.With(mContext).Load(SearchActivity.SearchImageLinks[position]).Into(image);
            text.Text = SearchActivity.SearchTitles[position];
            if (SearchActivity.SearchLinks[position].Contains("movie"))
            {
                text2.Text = "Movie";
            }
            else
            {
                text2.Text = "TV Show";
            }
        }
        image.Id = 2;
        //setting text

        text.Id = 1;
        text2.Id = 3;
        text3.Id = 4;
        text3.Text = (position + 1) + "";

        text.SetSingleLine(true);
        text.Ellipsize = Android.Text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;
        // setting layout
        int borderID = HelperClass.GetBorder(mContext);
        layout.SetBackgroundResource(borderID);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        textLayout.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
        textLayout.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentTop);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(180,250);
        imageLayout.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
        imageLayout.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, text.Id);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams text2Layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        text2Layout.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
        text2Layout.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, image.Id);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams text3Layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        text3Layout.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
        text3Layout.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, text2.Id);
        text3Layout.TopMargin = 5;

        //adding to layout
        layout.AddView(text, textLayout);
        layout.AddView(text2, text2Layout);
        layout.AddView(image, imageLayout);
        layout.AddView(text3, text3Layout);

        return layout;
    }

}
```

Scrolling into view:
`mGridView.SmoothScrollToPosition(lastListItems - 24);`

Getting Items from `ItemsGrid` class:
`mGridView.Adapter = new ItemsGrid(this, lastListItems, numberOfLinks, type);`

So if someone has any tips to share about how this can be achieved smoothly, please help me.
Thanks

Comment: When you add a new item, what do you add it to?

Comment: I add a set of 24 items every time and I call `mGridView.Adapter = new ItemsGrid(this, lastListItems, numberOfLinks, type);` with the correct position values to get the next items from the array lists.

Comment: You should be adding the items to a collection, and that collection will be tied to your view using an adapter. Then scrolling, everything will work.

Comment: I am afraid I will need a little guidance here as to how I am able to achieve this. I have done searches but so far found nothing which explains how do I bind ObservableCollection and  adapters. If you have any information that can help me please don't hesitate to tell.

Comment: There is an example [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/create_a_custom_adapter_for_contacts/)

Comment: I have found a nice example on this: http://blog.wislon.io/posts/2015/01/27/xamarin-android-gridview-with-infinite-scrolling
Seems to handle incremental loading also.